# How to completely uninstall Python 3.7 in a Windows 10 machine?

Tags: python, python-3.x, uninstallation

I had Python 3.7 installed prior to an Anaconda installation. I then uninstalled Anaconda with the "Add or remove programs" feature of Windows 10, and rebooted.

Afterwards, I tried uninstalling Python through the same method. A window from Python will pop up saying that the uninstallation was successful. However, Python will remain in the list of "Apps & features," despite me trying to uninstall it 5x afterwards. I am also able to open the Python IDE.

I am at a loss on what to do to fully uninstall it.

Comment: From what I learned, I installed the same installer of my python version, then I ran it and from there I uninstalled it.

Answer (score 0):

Download **IOBIT Uninstaller** software and use powerful uninstall from there to completely uninstall Python. It can also delete stubborn programs. You can download this software from this link [IObit Uninstaller](https://www.iobit.com/en/advanceduninstaller.php). After uninstalling, clean the broken registry items of Python. As you can do it manually but it's a difficult task. So you may download any registry cleaner to do that. I am personally using Wise Care 365 and it works great. You can download this from here [Wise Care 365](https://www.wisecleaner.com/wise-care-365.html). Both software is free.